# Decryption returning strange characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encryption, base64, chef-infra, decode

I have created an decryption script using base64 to decrypt passwords with Chef databags that I have previously encrypted using a different script.
 The script for decryption complies without throwing any errors although it returns a junk string with strange symbols.

An example of **encrypted string**:

```
fff: T3UZSkX4vsJxnWEaIMWK3w==
```

**When decoded:**

```
￯ﾾﾖ5p￯﾿ﾁ￯ﾾﾐ￯ﾾﾜ￯ﾾﾪ`￯ﾾﾱ,Ch￯﾿ﾎ￯﾿ﾸ￯﾿ﾤ
```

The part of script I am using to decrypt is,

```
#Call decryption method
item = decryptDatabag(project, domain)
puts(item["chef_password"])  
puts(item["Password"])   

secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("\\\\############\\ChefEncryptedDatabagKey\\#{@project}\\secret.txt")   .
item = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load(project, "EncryptedItem", secret)
```

It is also pulling from the file encrypted_data_bag_item.rb.

```
ALGORITHM = 'aes-256-cbc'

def [](key)
   value = @enc_hash[key]
   if key == "id" || value.nil?
      value
   else
      self.class.decrypt(value, @secret)
   end
end 

def self.decrypt(value, key)
   YAML.load(self.decipher(:decrypt, Base64.decode64(value), key))
end

def self.decipher(direction, data, key)
  decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(ALGORITHM)
  decipher.decrypt
  decipher.padding = 0
  decipher.send(direction)
  decipher.pkcs5_keyivgen(key)
  ans = decipher.update(data)
  ans &lt;&lt; decipher.final
  ans
end
```

The part of script I am using to encrypt is,

```
    @sourceDatabag = nil
    @sourceItems = Hash.new
    @sourceDatabag = @sourcerest.get_rest("/data/#{@databag}")
    if @sourceDatabag.has_key?("EncryptedItem")
        sourceItem = @sourcerest.get_rest("/data/#{@databag}/EncryptedItem") 
        targetItem = Chef::DataBagItem.new
        targetItem.data_bag(@databag)       
        sourceItem.each do |key, value|
                if value.end_with? ".lock"
                    print "#{@databag_name}: #{key} has already been encrypted!\n"
                    targetItem[key] = value
                elsif key != "id"
                    targetItem[key] = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.encrypt_value(value, @databag)
                    puts "Encrypted the #{key} item, and saved Databag #{@databag}\n"
                else
                    targetItem[key] = value
                end
        end 
    else
        puts "EncryptedKey item not found, quitting"
        exit(1)
    end
return 
rescue Net::HTTPServerException => hse
    puts "The #{@databag} databag does not exist, please create one before running this job"
end
```

end

Can anyone help me with this problem please?

Comment: That's a lot of code, and much of it isn't relevant to your problem. Please put together a smaller example. See http://sscce.org/ Please include important variables such as value of `ALGORITHM`. For an encrypt/decrypt problem, I also suggest: 1. Show your encryption routine. 2. Using a key just for the example, generate a new encrypted string, and share the key plus the known plaintext, so that anyone who is helping you knows when they have the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for shortening the example

Comment: I cannot see your error, and still think that supplying a valid key and known plaintext would help a lot. Your example problem output is likely to be just pseudo-random bytes interpreted as UTF-8. That is to be expected if you get any of encrypted text, algorithm, IV or key incorrect when decrypting and unfortunately does not say much about what could be wrong.

Comment: Before encryption: chef_password = password After encryption: chef-password = gA4hB7hBgyRFaEmFYLeHaQ==. Thank you for helping @Neil Slater

Comment: Sorry I meant encryption key, which I think you are calling "secret". Obviously don't share the real one. Without the full set of data to confirm a successful decrypt, it is very hard to tell whether a guess at the problem cause is correct.

Comment: The encryption key stored within the secret file is 'password'

Comment: I think you're encountering the same UTF-8 issue described here, https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/openssl/pull/13.

Comment: I cannot solve it. I'm a little wary of `pkcs5_keyivgen` - it's  a deprecated method for generating key and iv from a password. Are you sure the encryption routine is using the same key derivation? It would still help to show the encryption routine.

Comment: I think `Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.encrypt_value(value, @databag)` is a problem, and should be `Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.encrypt_value(value, @secret)` - assuming you have defined `@secret`

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with change that, still receiving the strange characters